# How can I augment this MILP by using equations with IFF conditions as cuts in GAMS?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gams-math, mixed-integer-programming

So I am trying to implement an algorithm in GAMS by augmenting a master problem with cuts after every iteration. The master problem is,

```
minimize w =-x - 10z
s.t. 
   -25x + 20z ≤ 30
   x + 2z ≤ 10
   2x - z ≤ 15
   -2x - 10z ≤ -15
   w >= -26
   w <= -22
where x and z are nonnegative integer variables.
```

After the 1st iteration i want to add the constraints,

```
1 ≤ x ≤ 6 IFF z ≤ 2
```

After the 2nd iteration I want to add the constraint,

```
2.5 ≤ x ≤ 8 IFF z ≤ 1
```

These two constraints augmenting the problem  restricts the solution space yielding (w=-22, x=2, z=2) as the optimal solution.

I tried to implement it in GAMS (with help from GAMSworld) by using dynamic sets with the following script. The final solution given out by GAMS however is (x=6, z=2). The optimal answer should be (x=2, z=2) as due to the constraint after the 2nd iteration, x cannot be greater than 2.5 unless z <= 1.

```
Integer Variable
x, z;

Free Variable w;

Set      k       /1*5/;

Set cut1set(k);
cut1set(k) = no;

Set cut2set(k);
cut2set(k) = no;

Equations
     obj, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11;

obj..    w =e= - x - 10 *z;
c1..     -25 * x + 20 * z =l= 30;
c2..     x + 2 * z =l= 10;
c3..     2 * x - z =l= 15;
c4..     - 2 * x - 10 * z =l= - 15;
c5..     w =g= -26;
c6..     w =l= -22;
* z is nonnegative integer
* z is nonnegative integer
c7..     z =g= 0;
c8(cut1set)..    x =l= 6;
c9(cut1set)..    x =g= 1;
c10(cut2set)..   x =l= 8;
c11(cut2set)..   x =g= 2.5;

Model mymodel /all/;

loop(k,
         solve mymodel use mip min w;

         if(ord(k) = 1 and z.l <= 2,
                 cut1set(k) = yes;
         );
         if(ord(k) = 2 and z.l <= 1,
                 cut2set(k) = yes;
         );
);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use the cuts from the augmented constraints with IFF conditions after the iterations ?  The way I have it right now is not constraining the solution space properly. I will really appreciate some help. Thank You!

Comment: I should add that unless z <= 1 x cannot be in the range [2.5, 8]. 
Is (2.5 <= x <= 8) <=> (z <= 1) a better way of expressing this ?

Answer (score 1):

May be this is easier:

```
solve mymodel using mip minimizing w;
if (z.l <= 2,
    x.lo = 1;
    x.up = 6;
    solve mymodel using mip minimizing w;
    if (z.l <= 1,
       x.lo = 2.5;
       x.up = 8;
       solve mymodel using mip minimizing w;
    );
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You just want two cut,One only in the first iteration and one in the second iteration.So the cuts should be added exactly in the same two steps,A conditional statement like cut1set(k)$(k.val=1) = yes; does this.

```
 Integer Variable x, z;

 Free Variable w;
 Set      k       /1*5/;
 Set cut1set(k);
 cut1set(k) = no;
Set cut2set(k);
 Cut2set(k) = no;

 Equations
 obj, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11;
 Obj..    w =e= - x - 10 *z;
  C1..     -25 * x + 20 * z =l= 30;
 c2..     x + 2 * z =l= 10;
 c3..     2 * x - z =l= 15;
 c4..     - 2 * x - 10 * z =l= - 15;
 c5..     w =g= -26;
c6..     w =l= -22;
 c7..     z =g= 0;
 c8(cut1set)..    x =l= 6;
 c9(cut1set)..    x =g= 1;
 c10(cut2set)..   x =l= 8;
 c11(cut2set)..   x =g= 2.5;

  Model mymodel /all/   ;

 loop(k,
     solve mymodel use mip min w;

     if(k.val = 1 and z.l <= 2,
             cut1set(k)$(k.val=1) = yes;
         );
     if(k.val= 2 and z.l <= 1,
             cut2set(k) $(k.val=2)= yes;
         );
 );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.

Comment: @N. Wouda 2  HI & GOOD , I added the explanation, I hope to help.

Comment: Hi Richard, I ran your script and it is giving me the solution of (x=6, z=2). However, from the constraint added after the 2nd iteration (2.5 <= x <= 8 iff z<= 1)  x cannot be equal to 6 as z is not less than or equal to 1. How do I enforce that ?

Comment: @Anonymous , Hi  , in 2end iteration z.val isn't less than or equal to 1 , then your  (2.5 <= x <= 8 iff z<= 1) condition ,doesn't check .

Comment: @Richard What I need to have, based on the value of x, is conditional ranges for value of variable x, which will be discontinuous. At z=2, x can take values between [1, 2.5[ and ]8, inf], without considering the bounds. If z.val isn't less than or equal to 1, it cannot take the values in [2.5, 8].  Right now at z=2, the range for x is [1, 6].

Comment: @Anonymous , You write ,At z=2, x can take values between [1, 2.5[ and ]8, inf],
Later you say  :Right now at z=2, the range for x is [1, 6].

That doesn't make any sense !!